# How to array months like "May June July August .." on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show Months and number of days of the month in function or widget.
I dont want to write list, i want to use `DateTime` and intl lib but i dont know what i can do.I want to do like this :

```dart
void main() => runApp(HomeApp());

class HomeApp extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(Build Context context) {
        String monthsShow() {
        DateTime months = new DateTime.? //what can i use at here?
        // what should i use this area?

    }
}
```

May i create a for loop ? How can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String generateListofMonths(DateTime time) {
    String returnString = '';
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      // increment the month value
      returnString += formatDate(DateTime(time.year, i, time.day), [M, '-']);
    }
    // remove the last dash (-)
    returnString = returnString.substring(0, returnString.length-1);
    return returnString;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // DateTime.now() is to get the current date and time
    String formattedDateTime = generateListofMonths(DateTime.now());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Flutter DateTime Display',
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[Text(formattedDateTime)],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can explore more on the `date_format` package but here is an example.

[image: Example]

Comment: thanks a lot but i want to show this way "June-July-August..- on the page or screen of emulator how can i do this without tablecalendar widget?

Comment: I would suggest you check out `date_format` package at [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/date_format)

Answer (score 1):

Use DateFormat like this

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(now);
```

To change the output of the format you can change the format string.

Check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html for the available options.

`"MMMM"` will show you the full month name. Or use `DateFormat.MMMM().format(now)`